# How to handle simultaneous save API requests in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, api, concurrency

I am trying to save new booking through API. Below is the sample code of save booking function.

```
public function save_booking(Request $request){
        $booking = new Booking;
        $booking->booking_number            = generate_booking_id();
        $booking->booking_type              = $request->input('bookingType');
        $booking->booking_date              = $request->input('bookingDate');
        $booking->booking_time              = $request->input('bookingTime');
        $booking->booking_status            = $request->input('bookingStatus');
        $booking->save();
}
```

Note - generate_booking_id() is a helper function to generate booking like BN-202105-0001 (Last four digits 0001 are calculated by adding total records count + 1 from booking table).

When two or more simultaneous save API requests trying to save new booking, same booking number is assigned to both requests. (E.g. Request 1 = BN-202105-0001, Request 2 = BN-202105-0001 and so on.)

I want to assign different booking number to each of simultaneous API request. (E.g. There are 4 simultaneous request trying to save new booking then for Request 1 = BN-202105-0001, Request 2 = BN-202105-0002, Request 3 = BN-202105-0003, Request 4 = BN-202105-0004)

How do I solve this concurrent request problem in Laravel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To be sure I understand your problem correctly: You have your own incremental-function but it sometimes generates a duplicate key, so you end up with duplicate booking-numbers?

Comment: @RobBiermann Actually my function generates correct booking number but when 2 request are saving record at same time then for both request same booking number is assigned.

Comment: Ok so then this is a classical concurrency issue. I would start by setting the booking_number field in the database to be unique so storing duplicates is impossible. Then, when you fail to save, because of duplicates, you simply increment the number and retry

Comment: @RobBiermann Thanks for your great suggestion.

Comment: I've also added a little more elaborate answer which would be most ideal in my opinion. With that approach you dont need to do error-handling, which can be a pain

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `generate_booking_id()` is reading the db simultaneously from two different requests and generating the booking id for you.

You can avoid this, by creating a `ON INSERT` trigger at the db level like the following to the update the `booking_number` for you instead of you manually doing it. The trigger will make sure to automatically update the `booking_number` after the booking has been created and not before it.

Assuming you are using MySQL: (Nevertheless, you could use the same approach in other database management systems)

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'bookings'.'update_booking_number'
AFTER INSERT ON 'bookings' FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE bookings b
      SET booking_number = (SELECT CONCAT('BN-202105-000',COUNT(*) + 1) FROM bookings) 
      WHERE b.id = NEW.id;
END;
```

**Alternate solution** could be to insert the booking record first into the db and then call the `generate_booking_id()` function to calculate the booking_number correctly and then update the record into the db:

```
 public function save_booking(Request $request){
            $booking = new Booking;
            $booking->booking_type              = $request->input('bookingType');
            $booking->booking_date              = $request->input('bookingDate');
            $booking->booking_time              = $request->input('bookingTime');
            $booking->booking_status            = $request->input('bookingStatus');
            $booking->save();

            $booking->booking_number            = generate_booking_id();
            $booking->save();
            
    }
```

Comment: Dhairyashil Nalawadeyashil I think you should give the trigger a try, you **wouldn't** have to modify the code in that case.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, you could try making the booking_number a property of your model. This property then combines a given prefix with the actual id of the booking. That way you do not need to create your own incremental function, and just assemble what you already got.

Example of the property:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Booking extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    function getBookingNumberAttribute() {
        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->attributes['booking_date']);
        $year = $date->year;
        $month = $date->format('m');
        $fourDigitId = sprintf('%04d', $this->attributes['id']);
        return "BN$year$month-$fourDigitId";
   }

    static function findByBookingNumber($booking_number) {
        $splitBookingNumber = explode('-', $booking_number);
        return self::where('id', intval($splitBookingNumber[1]));
   }
}
```

The function getBookingNumberAttribute functions as an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for the property: `booking_number`, so when you run:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$booking = Booking::create([
    'booking_date' => $now->format('Y-m-d'),
    'booking_time' => $now->format('H:i:s'),
    'booking_status' => 'new',
]);
dump($booking->booking_number);
```

You should always get a new ID, as the logic for creating the unique id is handled by the mysql database.

I've also added a method to show how to find a booking by its booking number.